# An ActionView::Template::Error can't convert Fixnum into String Ruby Racer Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, therubyracer

We included therubyracer gem with our Rails 4.0 application to improve performance on rendering actions that use coffeescript response files.  After rolling out the gem, we began seeing occasionally a "`ActionView::Template::Error`" "`can't convert Fixnum into String`".  The traceback just points to the first line of coffeescript so I'm thinking it may be related to therubyracer processing the file.  Has anyone else seen this issue?

Again, I don't believe it is related to the coffeescript code since the exact same code ran without the error until using therubyracer, but here it is anyway:

update.js.coffee:

```
$('#client_project_task').html('<%= j render(:partial => "client_project_task") %>');
$('form').effect('highlight', {duration: 800});
Tick.Timecard.init()
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try putting double quotes inside the html call.

Comment: I am sure that this error has caused by your partial code. This is behavior of `.js.erb`, it will not show error line of your partial. It will only show the origin for the call from `.js.erb`. Check your `partial` or post the code, if you think you need help.